# Filter certain SQL data formatted in one column into a new column

Tags: sql, split, flamerobin

Before I begin I found this to be most relevant with the research I have done.

[How to split the data from one column into separate columns using the contents of another column in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041716/how-to-split-the-data-from-one-column-into-separate-columns-using-the-contents-o)

Attached are pictures of my progress so far. How can I display this information such as it is shown in the excel file without disrupting the

```
GROUP BY
```

filter in my Query?

It's a Fishbowl Database, newest version. I am running the queries through Flamerobin which you see in the picture. Trying to organize the query to display correctly so I can format it into 'iReports' and export it into an excel spreadsheet like the one shown. Maybe there is some part of this that would better be done in excel?

Notice the numbers for Qty are different, that's ok right now.

My reputation is too low to post pictures I am sorry. Here are the two JPGs in my Dropbox. I really appreciate the help.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r2rw5r2awsyvzs9/AAAXXg27CMPOYtZFqPX3Dx6la?dl=0

Comment: please post the sample data and expected output

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jonathan. I have the dropbox link at the bottom with 2 pictures. Are those not what you mean?

Comment: Copy and paste the data into the question rather than pictures on another site, then highlight it and hit the `{}` button to format it as code, and try to distill it down to a sample that covers the bases without extra fluff.  I think it's best to have a question be self-contained and complete.

Comment: An Excel pivot table might get you close to the results you are after.